# PHP regex to find value of Apache Tile attribute

Tags: php, regex, apache-tiles

I want to use PHP to search a directory of files (views.xml files) and pull out values from any attributes named "window_title_key".

The attributes look like this:

```
<put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/views/login/content.vm" type="velocity" />
<put-attribute name="window_title_key" value="window_title_login_page" type="string"/>
```

For each file, I want to ignore all lines except those that start with `<put-attribute name="window_title_key"`.

Then, on those lines, I want to extract the value of that attribute.  In this example, the value would be `window_title_login_page`.

I want the result to be an array of all of the values of all `window_title_key` attributes.

What is the regex pattern I should use?

It should be flexible enough to allow for variable whitespace (before the word "value" and the double-quotes of the "name" property).

Comment: Don't use regex on xml!!!

Comment: Good point!  I should have realized that XML is MADE to be readable more easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your regex requirements:

```
/^\Q<put-attribute name="window_title_key" value="\E([^"]*)"/m
```

This should suffice. Take the matches from group 1. Variable whitespace is possible inside and after the value attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but that doesn't seem to work, even if I fudge the source views.xml files a bit.  I also updated the question (about whitespace).

Comment: Sorry, your solution DOES work for my question in the way that I asked it.  I made mistakes in the wording of my question.  Someone else just helped me find that `/<put-attribute name="window_title_key"\s+value="([^"]*)"/m` is the regex that I wanted.  (But I also agree with pguardiario that I shouldn't have been using regex to read from XML at all!)